# How get only validated fields?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have such validating rule:

```
'tags.*.tag_id' => 'sometimes|exists:tags,id',
'tags.*.is_main_tag' => 'sometimes|required_with:tags.*.tag_id|boolean',
```

How in controller get only `tags.*.tag_id`, but not `tags.*.some_fields`.
Or how setup `protected $fillable` in model?

Comment: What Laravel version are you using?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir 5.4

Comment: Setting fillable is as simple as having a `protected $fillable [ columns that you can mass assign ]` in your model. Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates under mass assignment

Comment: @apokryfos when I add `tags.*.tag_id` - field not fill correct!

Comment: that doesn't look like a correct database column name. Are you sure it's not just `tag_id` ?

Comment: @apokryfos fields `tags` is json. `tag_id`  is fields of elemet of JSON

Comment: Well denormalizing a database is bound to have negative consequences and this seems to be one of them. [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) might help sanitise your field data